# Find lines not starting with " in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I try to verify a CSV file where we had problems with line breaks.

I want to find all lines not starting with a `"`.

I am trying with `/!^"/gim` but the `!` negation is not working.

How can I negate `/^"/gim` properly?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In regex, the `!` does not mean negation; instead, you want to negate a character set with `[^"]`. The brackets, `[]`, denote a character set and if it starts with a `^` that means "not this character set".

So, if you wanted to match things that are not double-quotes, you would use `[^"]`; if you don't want to match any quotes, you could use `[^"']`, etc.

With Notepad++, you should be able to search with the following to find lines that don't start with the `"` character:

```
^[^"]
```

If you want to highlight the full line, use:

```
^[^"].*
```

Comment: @newfurniturey I think the confusing part is that the chevron (hat / caret) symbol has two meanings depending on context. Either 'starts with' or 'negation', or did I misunderstand?

Comment: What if I want it to Not have certain combination?
For example I want to add aliases to fieldnames in SQL queries unless there is one set (in SQL you set an alias by simply using "table.fieldname as alias"), so I have a regex for that, but how to make sure it only matches those without an alias.
(OTHERREGEX-HERE)(^([\s]+[Aa][Ss])) doesnt seem to work...

Comment: @MahNas92 That sounds like it deserves its own question on the site, would be too large of an answer for a comment like this one.

Comment: @newfurniturey maybe later on, but I can share my work-around in C# with others; I simply made a regex that fetches the last regex-pattern in a variable like this:  ([\s]+[Aa][Ss])?), and then I, with programing logic, check if this last line is empty or not to decide if it really is a match...

Answer (score 46):

In Notepad++ you can use the very usefull [negative lookahead](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Assertions)

In your case you can try the following:

```
^(?!")
```

If you want to match wholes lines add `.+` or `.{1,7}` or anything e.g.:

```
^(?!").*
```

will also match empty lines.

#### Explanation part

`^` line start

`(?!regexp)` negative lookahead part: this means that if the **regexp match**, the result will **not** be shown

Answer (score 10):

Step 1 - Match lines. **Find** dialog > **Mark** tab, you can bookmark lines that match.

Step 2 - Remove lines bookmarked OR Remove lines not bookmarked. Search > Bookmark > Remove Unmarked Lines or  Remove Bookmarked lines