# Regex: Match lines NOT starting with phrase

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I found this question about negative lookaheads, but it doesn't work for me in Regexr (which I use to validate regular expressions):
[Find lines not starting with " in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164518/find-lines-not-starting-with-in-notepad)

http://www.regexr.com/

I want to match every line that does not start with "Sold, ship now"

Currently, on regexr, when I use the expression `^(?!Sold, ship now)` on the following text:

```
Sold, ship now: [FreeEconomy Shipping]

Sold, NOT ship now: [FreeEconomy Shipping]

Sold, ship now: [FreeEconomy Shipping]
```

I receive 0 matches.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to post an image for this question. You can post your expression and sample data as text. Images should be used only when the problem cannot be demonstrated any other way. See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons images should be avoided.

Comment: Additionally, RegExr allows you to save your regex and test data, and link directly to that.  Providing a generic link to the RegExr site is no more helpful than posting an image of your data.  But all we really need is your code/sample data/whatever *as text*, so we can copy it into our own editor/IDE and work with it ourselves.

Comment: Can be done with basic regexp, but it would be of size `O(N²)` where N is the length of the string. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the multiline flag. Which, in the case of [regexr](http://www.regexr.com), can be activated like so:

[image: regexr multiline flag]

Also,  if you'd like to return the entirity of the lines that do not begin with `Sold, ship now`, I'd recommend utilizing dot plus in your expression:

```
^(?!Sold, ship now).+
```

Comment: Notepad++ is always in multiline mode, so I suspect the missing `.+` was the real problem.

Comment: Bless you. I had tried .+ it just wasn't in that screenshot.