# Regex in multi line config file, not equal to

Tags: java, regex

I've been trying to research this but I am struggling to find a relevant post. We use a config file for one of our services which looks like the following (Note that some of the names have spaces after the hash, and some have parameters):

```
#GetContactDetails
GetContactDetails.XXXXUser=USERNAME
GetContactDetails.XXXXPassword=PASSWORD
GetContactDetails.TestFlag=Y
GetContactDetails.EndPointURL=http://111.99.111.999/ENVNAME2/endpoint.xx
GetContactDetails.Timeout=40000
GetContactDetails.LoggingFlag=Y

# GetContactDetails
GetContactDetails.XXXXUser=USERNAME
GetContactDetails.XXXXPassword=PASSWORD
GetContactDetails.TestFlag=Y
GetContactDetails.EndPointURL=http://111.99.111.999/ENVNAME2/endpoint.xx
GetContactDetails.Timeout=40000
GetContactDetails.LoggingFlag=Y

# GetContactDetails Parameters
GetContactDetails.XXXXUser=USERNAME
GetContactDetails.XXXXPassword=PASSWORD
GetContactDetails.TestFlag=Y
GetContactDetails.EndPointURL=http://111.99.111.999/ENVNAME2/endpoint.so
GetContactDetails.Timeout=40000
GetContactDetails.LoggingFlag=Y
```

Essentially there are 4 different variations:

```
#servicename
# servicename
#servicename parameters
# servicename parameters
```

I want to be able to run a replace on this text file, leaving me with the names of each service (Just the lines beginning with #). Meaning I need to identify anything that IS NOT equal to the patter of the # lines.  All the combinations I have tried,I can't get it to identify everything else.

Any suggestions?

**P.S. (from comments)**

I was hoping to use regex as there is an existing Java service which can replace, using regex. To go down that route would require writing a Java service and also deploying that, albeit not too big of a task but I'd like to avoid it if at all possible.

Comment: Using  Notepad++ or anything else? See [*Find lines not starting with " in Notepad++*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164518/find-lines-not-starting-with-in-notepad).

Comment: At the minute I've been testing variations on regexr.com. The actual implementation of this is going to be on an integration server which uses Java.

Comment: If it is for Java, do not use regex. Just read line by line, and only grab the lines that start with `#`.

Comment: I was hoping to use regex as there is an existing Java service which can replace, using regex. To go down that route would require writing a java service and also deploying that, albeit not too big of a task but I'd like to avoid it if at all possible.

Comment: See my answer tailored for Java specifically.

Answer (score 1):

```
Search: ^[^#].*[\r\n]*
Replace: <blank>
```

The key part is `^[^#]`, which means "the first character is not a hash"

You need the `[\r\n]*` to also match the newline (dot does not match newline chars), otherwise you'll be left with blank lines (instead of deleting them).

Comment: Two points: 1) `^[^#].*[\r\n]+` won't replace empty lines, and 2) won't remove the last line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew fair enough - swapped + for *

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the best approach for this task is reading the file line by line and collect lines starting with `#`.

If you want to apply a regex to the whole file contents, it should be

```
.replaceAll("(?m)^(?!#).*[\r\n]*", "")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sD6wI9/1)

**Explanation**:

- `(?m)^` - start of a *line* (`(?m)` is the inline modifier making `^` match a beginning of a line, not string)
- `(?!#)` - makes sure the first symbol on the line is not `#` (if it is, no match is returned)
- `.*` - zero or more symbols other than a newline
- `[\r\n]*` - zero or more CR or LF symbols (in Java 8, it can be replaced with `"\\R*"`)

For your exact environment, I think you can use

```
[^#].*
```

And - to also match empty strings - if they can be removed at all there:

```
^$
```

You say `[^#].*\..*` is working for you. Here is what it actually does:

- `[^#]` - matches a char other than `#`
- `.*` - matches 1 or more chars other than a newline as many as possible up to the last
- `\.` - literal `.`
- `.*` - matches 1 or more chars other than a newline up to the end of line.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it helped me understand it a lot more. I tried to use this with the replace service already in place and it didn't seem to pick up what I wanted. I have since found that
[^#].*\..* identifies everything other than the lines beginning with #, and performs exactly as I had hoped for. Unfortunately I do not get much experience using Regex, so sometimes the most simple / easy solutions seem to get overlooked!

Comment: What are the service regex settings? Are you sure it is Java regex, and not some RE library?

Comment: I added two more simple patterns and explained your pattern.

Comment: It has had me questioning whether it is Java or not. The service itself is a Java service. Unfortunately it's built in from the software vendor, who has locked it down so that I cannot see the source code. It is on that basis I have had to assume it is Java (Most other built-in services are). Thank you for expanding on what the working regex does also. It was the '.' that made me think of this differently, in the all the lines I did not want contained it. Therefore with the advice provided here I was able to experiment a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
#\s?(\w+)\s?(\w+)?
```

in notepad++ ctrl+h->paste code -> replace with ' '

Comment: That identifies all the lines that do begin with #, which is somewhat similar to what I had before. Although I'm trying to select all lines that do not start with '#' , and then replace them with '' to leave only the # lines remaining.

Comment: I'm confused - so You want to leave lines begining with '#' or delete them?

Comment: I want to leave them, and delete every other line that does not begin with '#'

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to be working fine for the intended purpose. Posting here in case it becomes useful for anyone browsing this question. Thanks for all the help & advice.

```
[^#].*\..*
```

Comment: You do not need to post the answer yourself. There are people who helped you. Please give them credit.

Comment: I will do. Apologies I do not use this site much. Is posting what I found to be the answer not useful also?

Comment: Your solution is not in line with the question. I doubt it is useful for other readers.